# Instantiating a class in the same .dll using reflection based on the class name?

Tags: c#, reflection

This should be simple but I can't find anywhere that tells me how to do this. I've got a class, it's in the same dll as the one I am using to do this.

All I want to do is something like.

```
thing.InstanceClass("ClassName");
```

I would like to do this without doing:

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");
```

And that is because the classes I would like to instance using reflection are in the same assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Type instanceType = Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.SomeType");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(instanceType);
```

You can resolve it through `Type.GetType(...)` if the assembly is already loaded into the AppDomain.

If you need the assembly you can use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`, or possibly `typeof(SomeType).Assembly` where `SomeType` is in your target assembly.

Comment: `Type.GetType(string)` does not search for types in every assembly in the AppDomain.  [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx): *"If typeName includes the namespace but not the assembly name, this method searches only the calling object's assembly and Mscorlib.dll, in that order."*  So as long as this code is compiled into the assembly where `SomeNamespace.SomeType` exists, this will work.  Otherwise, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [System.Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) is the framework method you seek.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a known (referenced, not COM etc.) type within your project, then the best way is to use the strongly-typed [`CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx) function:

```
MyClass instance = Activator.CreateInstance<MyClass>();
```

This will save much of performance cost since there is no boxing/unboxing.